# Doubt on handling mutable fields in IP header when computing digest or authentication data

Tags: ipv4, ip, ipv6, authentication, rfc

I read [*RFC 4302, IP Authentication Header, Section 3.3.3, Integrity Check Value Calculation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4302#section-3.3.3). In page 13, it is mentioned that the fields which are mutable during transit, like TTL or hop count, are set to zero.

If they are set to zero then how can we keep track of hop count?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding what that is telling you. Simply for the purposes of the calculation, you use zero for those fields; you don't actually change those fields to zero for the packet.